# Create HTTP-request in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers

Is is possible to create and send a similar HTTP-request using the POST-method in JavaScript?

```
POST register.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: hi/iq
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.2) Gecko/20021126
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,
video/x-mng,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif;q=0.2,text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-us, en;q=0.50
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress;q=0.9
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8;q=0.66, *;q=0.66
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------29772313742745
Content-Length: 452
-----------------------------29772313742745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
J.Doe
-----------------------------29772313742745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
abuse@spamcop.com
-----------------------------29772313742745
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-upload"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
test data with some high ascii: ¿Como estás?
-----------------------------29772313742745--
```

The most important things I need are in the last 13 lines (form text data + form file data).
The data (text+file) are to be retrieved in a PHP file serverside.
I have already tried using XMLHttpRequest and Formdata, but I can't get it working properly.

The attempt that makes most sense imo is:

```
    var fd3 = new FormData();
    fd3.append('mode', 'end');    // set $_POST['mode']="end"
    fd3.append('file', image.jpg);    // set $_FILES['file']=image.jpg

    var xhr3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr3.open("POST", "pages/upload_arc3d.php", false);
    xhr3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr3.send(fd3);
```

Comment: Show what you've tried with `XMLHttpRequest`. What didn't work for you?

Comment: Should be possible.  Show us your best attempt so far.

Comment: simplest implementaion is jQuery , can serialize a form and post it with just a few lines of code see  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: For regular form text input, i used serialize() already. But I don't manage to combine it with form file input. (also edited my question)

Comment: Do these things by ajax jquery would help